# Uninitialized constant in module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics-api

I have this controller

```
  module GaReporting
    module Api

      class GaGatheringController < ApplicationController
        client = Google::APIClient.new(...)
      end
    end
  end
```

However I get an uninitialized constant error for the 
`uninitialized constant GaReporting::Api::GaGatheringController::Google`

This is curious since this line works fine when I just call it in a "normal" controller that is not inside any modules.

How do I fix this and why is it not working?

Comment: Call as `::Google::APIClient.new(...)`...

Comment: `uninitialized constant Google` now. How do I go up two levels?

Answer (score 1):

adding `require 'google/api_client'` in the `class` does the trick. Interesting that in the module the `require` statement is -- pardon the pun -- required since in a regular controller it is not.